# Target audience for a stylesheet

Tags: audience-targeting

Is it possible?  Have a button hidden right now by css, but want to open it up to certain groups.  I tried using a CEWP with a simple jQuery script as a test and couldn't get it to work.  Is there a way to do this?

I know you can use a list and use target audience on that with a content query, but that won't work for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was as simple as the question was stated.  I was using jQuery and editing the css that way initially and it wasn't working.  When I used a regular stylesheet with a CEWP it works perfectly.

Comment: Don't use a CEWP, use a Script editor webpart.

All webparts support audiences.