# Assign a specific audience to an image in a WebPart

Tags: audience-targeting

I'm trying to have an image show up within a webpart based on the authorization group of a user.

Is there a way to assign a specific audience to an image within a WebPart rather then the entire WebPart?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean with image show up based within a webpart ? what's the type of this web part ? by the way, the audience applied at the entire web part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPSecurityTrimmedControl in webpart design file,

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat=”server” Permissions=”ViewPages”>
//Only users with ViewPages permissions will be able to see this content.
<img src="test.gif" alt="test" height="42" width="42">
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

SPSecurityTrimmedControl which performs the security trimming of the child controls inside it. Just include our control inside this control and it will be displayed or hidden based on the permission specified.

Here is detail example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/security-trimmed-control-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful.  Instead of displaying the image based on a specific permission, is there a way to have it displayed using the group ID?

Comment: We can not add sharepoint group in SPSecurityTrimmedControl.  this thread may help you. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112337/security-trimmed-content-based-on-group-membership-target-audience